# GenericRecord to GenericRecord using sub schema (reader schema) without Encode/Decode

Tags: avro

I am trying an efficient way to create a GenericRecord from another GenericRecord using a subschema (reader schema) without using Encoder/Decoder. For example I have the following schemas

```
    String fullSchema = "{\"namespace\": \"example.avro\",\n" +
            " \"type\": \"record\",\n" +
            " \"name\": \"User\",\n" +
            " \"fields\": [\n" +
            "     {\"name\": \"name\", \"type\": \"string\"},\n" +
            "     {\"name\": \"favorite_number\",  \"type\": [\"int\", \"null\"]},\n" +
            "     {\"name\": \"favorite_number2\",  \"type\": [\"int\", \"null\"]},\n" +
            "     {\"name\": \"favorite_color\", \"type\": [\"string\", \"null\"]}\n" +
            " ]\n" +
            "}";

    String readerSchema = "{\"namespace\": \"example.avro\",\n" +
            " \"type\": \"record\",\n" +
            " \"name\": \"User\",\n" +
            " \"fields\": [\n" +
            "     {\"name\": \"name\", \"type\": \"string\"},\n" +
            "     {\"name\": \"favorite_number2\",  \"type\": [\"int\", \"null\"]}\n" +
            " ]\n" +
            "}";
```

I would like to find a way to do something like this without any code and decoder, I know it is possible using a reader schema but because performance reasons, I would like to avoid this option, my real schemas are much more bigger and complex (nested structures and arrays)

```
    GenericRecord record = new GenericData.Record(new Schema.Parser().parse(fullSchema));
    record.put("name", "Jhon");
    record.put("favorite_number", 1);
    record.put("favorite_number2", 2);
    record.put("favorite_color", "red");

    GenericRecord subRecord = copy(record, readerSchema);
```